# Дёргаются картинки при hover в firefox, как этого избежать?

Tags: css, вёрстка, firefox, frontend

Есть простой див с img внутри, на этом диве висит hover, при hover на картинку накладывается opacity 0.6 c transition 0.5s. В firefox и только в нём при наведении на этот элемент он дёргается, если transition убрать-то перестаёт.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
 }

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div><a href=""><img src=""></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что при использовании transition возникает перерисовка блока. Из-за этого могут возникать такие подергивания. Чтобы решить проблему, советую воспользоваться "нулевым" хаком:

```
a {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Суть этого метода заключается в том, что при обнаружении браузером этого свойства он отправляет рендеринг данного блока на GPU. В свою очередь графический ускоритель выполняет свойство, а затем кеширует его результат в своей видеопамяти.